# How to bind to event.time variable in parent scope from a directive with isolate scope without using $parent in directive?

Tags: angularjs, isolate-scope

```js
angular.module('hfp.calendar')
    .controller('printPreviewCntrl', ['$scope', 'htmlFromServer',
     function($scope, htmlFromServer){

         $scope.htmlReceived = htmlFromServer;
            $scope.event = {};

}])
.directive('compile', function($compile, $timeout) {

    return {
     restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   $timeout(function() {
    element.html(scope.$eval(attrs.compile));
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
   });
  }
 };

})
.directive('initModel', function($compile) {

 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
   eventField: '=initModel'
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   scope.eventField = element[0].innerText;
   element.attr('ng-bind', '$parent.' + attrs.initModel); // why do i have to use $parent here to make it work ?
   element.removeAttr('init-model');
   $compile(element)(scope);
  }
 };

});
```

```html
<!-- clientside html -->
<input type="text" ng-model="event.time">
<div compile="htmlReceived">

</div>

<!-- html coming from server -->
<div init-model="event.time">
 10:30 AM
</div>
```

I want to bind to the parent scope var event.time from **initModel** directive but it only works when i use $parent to refer to the var in parent scope. Can i achieve this binding without using $parent ?

Comment: Try using `controller as` syntax

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to implement that directive with isolate scope. Simply use the `$parse` service:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive('initModel', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        //scope: {
        // eventField: '=initModel'
        //},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var setter = $parse(attrs.initModel).assign;
            setter(scope, elem.text().trim());
            scope.$watch(attrs.initModel, function(value) {
                elem.text(value);
            });
        }        
     };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-init="event={}">
    <input type="text" ng-model="event.time">
    <div init-model="event.time">
        10:30 AM
    </div>
</body>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $parse Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).

Comment: @ georgeawg, i am under the impression it is always better to access parent scope variables through isolate scope in a directive, and your solution seems to be compromising on that. doesn't it ? the scope you are using inside directive is the prototypically inherited scope from the parent, right ?

Comment: This is an attribute directive that creates no new scope, inherited or isolate. There are many core directives of AngularJS which avoid creating a scope: `ng-class`, `ng-click`, `ng-show`, etc. With attrubute directives it is wise to avoid the overhead of creating a scope which may conflict with other attribute directives.